# Каким образом foreach узнаёт, что коллекция была изменена?

Tags: c#

Как известно, если во время работы `foreach` коллекция, которую он перебирает будет изменена (в другом потоке, например), то произойдёт исключение.
Но как устроен этот механизм исключений? Кто ответственен за обнаружение изменения? Должен ли я при разработке своих коллекций принимать какие-то меры для поддержки этого поведения или всё всегда будет заводиться *из коробки*?

Comment: он хранит версию коллекции и сравнивает ее на каждом проходе

Comment: [How do foreach loops work in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/398996/2881286) похоже все-таки сама коллекция должна следить за этим, вернее `Enumerator` который используется

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Цикл `foreach` эквивалентен приблизительно следующему коду:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var enumerator = ((IEnumerable<int>)a).GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var item = enumerator.Current;
    // ... тело цикла ...
}
```

Таким образом, все зависит от реализации метода `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` в конкретной коллекции.
Для большинства встроенных в .Net коллекций этот метод возвращает класс, который и следит за приватным свойством `version` коллекций. Которое, в свою очередь увеличивается на 1 каждый раз, когда коллекция меняется.

*За исключением одного бага, о котором я уже писал в майкрософт, но толку это не поимело. Метод `List<T>.Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)` не вызывает инкремент версии.*

Comment: с сортировкой забавно.

Comment: А баг таки исправили в какой-то из новых версий, посмотрел специально этот метод.

Comment: @trollingchar, нет, в 4.8 не исправлено: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,984

Comment: @АндрейNOP странно. У меня в декомпиляторе показывает что там есть инкремент

Comment: @АндрейNOP https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs,1031

Comment: @PetSerAl, подозрительная ссылка. Это исходники .NET Core или чего? Не понятно как посмотреть другую версию .NET

Comment: @trollingchar, декомпилируете .NET Core или что?

Comment: Я исправлял это в [dotnet/coreclr](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) и в [dotnet/corert](https://github.com/dotnet/corert). Полагаю, там же это и осталось, а в .NET Framework не пошло.

Comment: @АндрейNOP я Mono смотрел. Наверно потому и разные результаты.

Answer (score 4):

> Должен ли я при разработке своих коллекций принимать какие-то меры для
>   поддержки этого поведения или всё всегда будет заводиться из коробки?

А вот это зависит от того, что у вас за коллекции.

Коллекция, всегда возвращающая рандомные элементы - точно не должна об этом задумываться.

Коллекция, работающая с сетью вполне может догружать данные на ходу - аналогично, я бы не падал изза изменения содержимого.

Опирайтесь на предметную логику, а не на массовость поведения.

Answer (score 4):

Из декомпилированного кода класса `List<T>`:

```
public class List<T> : ... {
    ...
    private int _version;
    ...

    public void ForEach(Action<T> action) {
        if (action == null)
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.action);
        int version = this._version;
        for (int index = 0; index < this._size && version == this._version; ++index)
            action(this._items[index]);
        if (version == this._version)
            return;
        ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion();
    }

    public List<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return new List<T>.Enumerator(this);
    }

    ...

    public struct Enumerator : ... {
        ...
        private int _version;
        ...

        internal Enumerator(List<T> list) {
            ...
            this._version = list._version;
            ...
        }

        ...

        public bool MoveNext() {
            List<T> list = this._list;
            if (this._version != list._version || (uint) this._index >= (uint) list._size)
                return this.MoveNextRare();
            this._current = list._items[this._index];
            ++this._index;
            return true;
        }

        private bool MoveNextRare() {
            if (this._version != this._list._version)
                ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion();
            this._index = this._list._size + 1;
            this._current = default (T);
            return false;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Как видно из кода, `List` хранит номер своей версии, и при создании `Enumerator`а этот номер версии записывает в его поле. Тот проверяет это поле в методе `MoveNext` на соответствие таковому у `List`а, и при несоответствии кидает исключение:

```
internal static void ThrowInvalidOperationException_InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion() {
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."
    );
}
```

Аналогичная проверка производится в методе `ForEach`.

Номер версии инкрементируется каждый раз, когда у `List`а вызывается метод, изменяющий его содержимое, а именно:

- Запись по индексу;
- Добавление элемента(ов) или коллекции;
- Очистка;
- Вставка элемента(ов);
- Удаление элемента(ов);
- Переворачивание списка;
- Сортировка.

Если хранимый тип - ссылочный, то его изменение не считается изменением коллекции и не меняет версию. То есть `list[i] = something` меняет, а `list[i].Update()` - нет.

И таки да, если во время перечисления списка провести над списком 2<sup>32</sup> операций до того, как перечислитель попытается перейти к следующему элементу, ошибки не выкинется. Запустим такой вот веселый код (выполнение занимает меньше минуты, и можно смотреть прогресс от 0 до 65536):

```
var list = new List <uint> {1};
Console.WriteLine (list [0]);
Console.ReadKey (true);
foreach (uint i in list) {
    for (uint j = 1; j != 0; ++j) {
        list [0] = j;
        if ((j & 65535) == 0) Console.WriteLine (j >> 16);
    }
    list [0] = 0;
    Console.WriteLine ("все еще не упало");
}
Console.WriteLine (list [0]);
```

Вывод:

```
1
<здесь жмем любую клавишу, чтобы не потерять 1 в этих логах прогресса эксперимента>
0
1
2
...
65534
65535
все еще не упало
0
```

Коллекция изменилась, а программа этого не заметила!

Если изменить число изменений, например, удалив цикл `for`, то мы увидим следующее:

```
1
<жмем любую клавишу>
все еще не упало

Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```