# Переменная _version в библиотченом классе ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net

Изучаю библиотечный класс ArrayList и не могу понять какую функцию несет переменная `private int _version;` ? Строка 48:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,48

```
public class ArrayList : IList, ICloneable
{
    private Object[] _items;
    [ContractPublicPropertyName("Count")]
    private int _size;
    private int _version;
    [NonSerialized]
    private Object _syncRoot;

    private const int _defaultCapacity = 4;
    private static readonly Object[] emptyArray = EmptyArray<Object>.Value; 

    // Note: this constructor is a bogus constructor that does nothing
    // and is for use only with SyncArrayList.
    internal ArrayList( bool trash )
    {
    }

    // Constructs a ArrayList. The list is initially empty and has a capacity
    // of zero. Upon adding the first element to the list the capacity is
    // increased to _defaultCapacity, and then increased in multiples of two as required.
    public ArrayList() {
        _items = emptyArray;  
    }
```

Comment: Она нужна, чтобы перечислитель мог выкинуть исключение, если список был изменён во время перечисления. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,2127

Comment: Версия меняется при любых изменениях коллекции, а при перечислении проверяется, что между шагами версия не изменилась. @PetSerAl, ответы - в ответы :)

Comment: См. также https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588924/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Переменная `_version` служит для отслеживания модификации списка. Перечислитель списка отслеживает изменение версии и [выбрасывает исключение](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,2127), если список был изменён во время перечисления:

```
// Implements an enumerator for a ArrayList. The enumerator uses the
// internal version number of the list to ensure that no modifications are
// made to the list while an enumeration is in progress.
```